# Brightway - lci calculation

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, brightway

I am doing a tutorial in brightway following the online seminar available at this webpage https://github.com/PoutineAndRosti/Brightway-Seminar-2017/blob/master/Day%201%20AM/2%20-%20BW%20structure%20and%20first%20LCAs.ipynb

Everything works well up to the section: 
2.1) General syntax of LCA calculations

In particular, when I run the command:

```
[In]  myFirstLCA_quick.lci()
```

I have an error message in the output:

> ```
> myFirstLCA_quick.lci()    # Builds matrices, solves the system, generates an LCI matrix.   File
> ```
>
> "/home/dario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py", line
>   278, in lci
>       self.load_lci_data(builder)   File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py", line
>   177, in load_lci_data
>       builder.build(self.database_filepath)   File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bw2calc/matrices.py",
>   line 143, in build
>       array = load_arrays(paths)   File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bw2calc/utils.py",
>   line 21, in load_arrays
>       assert all(os.path.isfile(fp) for fp in paths) AssertionError

Additional information:

My operative system is **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**.
I use **Python 2.7.14** :: Anaconda, Inc. and I have installed if I type **conda list** in the terminal, these is the version of brightway detected:

- brightway2                2.1.1                      py_1    cmutel
- bw2analyzer               0.9.4                      py_0    cmutel
- bw2calc                   1.6.2                      py_0    cmutel
- bw2data                   3.0.rc1                    py_0    cmutel
- bw2io                     0.6.RC3                    py_0    cmutel
- bw2parameters             0.6.1.2                    py_3    cmutel

Additional information (after Chris answer):

These lines of code:

```
for db in bw.databases:
         print(db, len(bw.Database(db)))
```

return:

> (u'ecoinvent 2.2', 4087)
>
> (u'biosphere3', 4029)

These lines of code:

```
for db in bw.databases:
         print(db, len(bw.Database(db)))
```

return:

> (u'ecoinvent 2.2', 4087)
>
> (u'biosphere3', 4029)

These lines:

```
 import brightway2 as bw
 for db in bw.databases:
    print bw.Database(db).process()
```

return

> None
>
> None

Could you help me?

Thank you in advance

Dario

Answer (score 0):

This *shouldn't* happen. Check to make sure that your databases actually exist and have activities:

```
import brightway2 as bw
for db in bw.databases:
    print(db, len(bw.Database(db)))
```

This might help also:

```
import brightway2 as bw
for db in bw.databases:
    bw.Database(db).process()
```

Comment: Dear @Chris, first of all, thank you for your help. I have run the code you suggested and I added in the description the results. Maybe, the problem could be linked to the processes that return None. Do you have suggestions. Thank you. Dario

Comment: @dario-daddà-turres Is this still a question? Calling `.process()` should return `None`, it writes the files to disk.